# The argument type 'CameraDescription?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'CameraDescription'

Tags: flutter, dart

```dart
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
import 'package:firebase_ml_vision/firebase_ml_vision.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:gass_in/Views/utils_scanner.dart';

class Camera extends StatefulWidget {
  const Camera({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CameraState createState() => _CameraState();
}

class _CameraState extends State<Camera> {
  bool isWorking = false;
  CameraController? cameraController;
  FaceDetector? faceDetector;
  Size? size;
  List<Face>? faceslist;
  CameraDescription? description;
  CameraLensDirection cameraDirection = CameraLensDirection.front;

  initCamera() async {
    description = await UtilsScanner.getCamera(cameraDirection);

    cameraController = CameraController(description!, ResolutionPreset.medium);

    faceDetector = FirebaseVision.instance.faceDetector(const FaceDetectorOptions(
      enableClassification: true,
      minFaceSize: 0.1,
      mode: FaceDetectorMode.fast,
    ));

    await cameraController!.initialize().then((value) {
      if (!mounted) {
        return;
      }
      cameraController!.startImageStream((imageFromStream) {
        if (!isWorking) {
          isWorking = true;
        }
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

The code for a Camera class in a Flutter project requires editing for correct camera initialization and other improvements. The `initCamera` method's implementation is not complete, leading to an error regarding the `cameraController` initialization.The `initCamera` needs to be completed to ensure proper initialization of the `cameraController` object which is instantiated within this method. Additionally, there are issues with minor typing errors in the code that need fixing. The syntax and formatting of the code can be improved as well. These issue are fixed in the modified code above.